# Using user-defined build settings in plist file

Tags: ios, plist

I have created a user defined build settings where I configure URL's. I then use the variable in the plist file in 'LSApplicationQueriesSchemes' and I when I use canOpenURL I see am not able use the app URL specified.

***My build settings:***

[image]

***My plist file with 'LSApplicationQueriesSchemes':***

[image]

However it works fine when I directly add URL to 'LSApplicationQueriesSchemes'.

***This works fine:***

[image]

I wish to add URL's based on different build types hence I am using user-defined build settings for it.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong, it always display $(SOMETHING) when you use variable, that's the way Xcode shows that you use a dynamic value in your Info.plist. To verify, you can open your archived package: Products -> [YOUR_PRODUCT_NAME].app -> Show Package Contents -> open your Info.plist -> now you will see the real value of LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. Also as I see in your settings, be aware that you didn't set Release value for LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, so in Release build it will be empty.